# How to hide Extension ( for eg .aspx ) in the URL?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

How to hide Extension ( for eg .aspx ) in the  URL ?

Comment: FWIW, the methods listed below are probably "what you want", but you can achieve the same result by setting whatever page you want to be the "default" page IIS returns, and having every page in it's own folder. Then you can just write out folder names, and IIS will load the appropriate file. Don't make it too strange, or it would be confusing.

Comment: @silky though this is possible... it's a very convolution solution. Especially with someone who is working with C# and can execute URLRewriting in less than 1/2 the time it takes to actually build that folder structure.  URLRewriting literally takes minutes to get up and running.

Comment: @rockinthesixstring "Convolution" isn't a word (in the way you use it). I prefixed my comment with "FWIW", and it's *already done* with typical pages such as "default.aspx" (and that's what I'm suggesting). My comment is essentially saying "Hey, this is already in place if you name your pages default.aspx and put them in folders". I would hope that that is clear to anyone and I should not have had to clarify.

Comment: Awe c'mon ... Convolution Solution... say it a few times... it has a ring to it ;-) - anyways... I wasn't saying you're wrong.  I just said that it would take more time and effort to do it that way than to implement a VERY simple URLRewriting system.

Comment: @rockinthesixstring: Sorry, it's exam time and I have no sense of humour at the moment :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you referring to URL Rewriting?

[Tip/Trick: Url Rewriting with ASP.NET](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

[URL Rewriting](http://dotnetblogger.com/search.aspx?q=urlrewriting) is one good option.

Another option is to use URL Routing with [MVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668201.aspx) or [Web Forms](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd347546.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I think ideally you'd want to use ASP.NET MVC.

If you use MVC as your website paradigm, the way that arguments are passed to the Model is through the actual addressing of the URL.

So you can then use address suffixes like: /do/useraccount

This is also what is being pushed by Microsoft and the ideas invested in ASP.NET 4.0 as they have included tools for making Model View Controller easier to implement.

Answer (score 0):

`Your Website < .NET 3.5 SP1 :-` use third-party URL Rewriting (e.g Intelligencia URL Rewriter)
`Your Website >= .NET 3.5 SP1 :-` use built-in URL Routing (e.g "MapPageRoute")